# How to use single LinkButton in a Gridview to update TextBox elsewhere on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**Scenario:** 
I have a GridView named gvpat on my .aspx page. This GridView has five columns.

1. Hour
2. 00 Min
3. 15 Min
4. 30 Min
5. 45 Min

Each column except the **Hour** has a LinkButton.
What I want is when the LinkButton is clicked, it will look at the *Hour* column to get the hour and then look at the column the LinkButton resides in to get the minutes. And put the time in a TextBox named txtCustTime elsewhere on the .aspx page.
For example if a button is clicked on the row that contains the Hour 1PM and the column that button resides in is  15 Min then the value entered in the txtCustTime will equal 13:15

Here are visuals of the GridView for AM/PM 
Here is the AM
[image]

Here is the PM

[image]

Now the **Change to PM** and **Change to AM** buttons simply rebind the grid when pressed (*I wrote a function that binds the grid to the data*) that is working and not apart of this question

**Scenario END**

**My problem:** When a LinkButton is pressed I call a function like this: For example lets say the user presses a LinkButton in the **45 Min** Column and lets say they press the button on row 12AM or 12PM depending what time of the day they are looking at.

```
protected void gvpat_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "GetTime45")
    {
        //Get rowindex
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //Get Row
        GridViewRow gvr = gvpat.Rows[rowindex];
        //Sets the label value for the linked button that was clicked
        LinkButton lb = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
        if (gvpat.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text == "45 Min")
        {
            Label myLabel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblhr");
            if (myLabel.Text == "12AM") { txtCustTime.Text = "00:45:00"; }
            if (myLabel.Text == "12PM") { txtCustTime.Text = "12:45:00"; }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is when pressing the LinkButton while looking at the "AM" view, 
txtCustTime is correctly set to 00:45:00

But if the user is looking at the "PM" view and presses the LinkButton,
txtCustTime is incorrectly set to blank. When it should be 12:45:00

**NOTES**:
lblhr - is the name of the control that holds the value in the GridView under the **Hour** column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably overthinking it. All you need to do is bind a range of the correct time slots. So if you have the following GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="System.DateTime" 
  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.ToLongTimeString() %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="00 Min">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item %>'>O</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="15 Min">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item.AddMinutes(15) %>'>O</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="30 Min">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item.AddMinutes(30) %>'>O</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="45 Min">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item.AddMinutes(45) %>'>O</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note the use of `ItemType="System.DateTime"`. This will ensure we can work with a DateTime object all across the GridView and in code behind.

Now bind some data to the GridView.

```
GridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(00, 12).Select(i => new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, i, 0, 0));
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now the GridView has 12 rows with DateTime objects. Now the only thing left to do is handle the clicking of the LinkButton with a `CommandArgument` for the time block. Simply cast the CommandArgument to a DateTime object in code behind and you're done.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(e.CommandArgument);
    Label1.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm");
}
```